# What is Comparable[] in Java?

Tags: java

I found a code where `Comparable[]` written preceding the array name `a`. 
I don't understood what's `Comparable[] a` and why `Comparable[]` needed to declare before an array name `a`.

```
public static void merge(Comparable[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi)
{
    // Merge a[lo..mid] with a[mid+1..hi].
    int i = lo, j = mid+1;
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Copy a[lo..hi] to aux[lo..hi].
        aux[k] = a[k];
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Merge back to a[lo..hi].
        if (i > mid) a[k] = aux[j++];
        else if (j > hi ) a[k] = aux[i++];
        else if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j++];
        else a[k] = aux[i++];
}
```

Comment: It's an array just like any other array.  It's an array of the type called `Comparable`.

Comment: what's the difference between the comparable [] array? and normal array?

Comment: @Zakk What in your mind is a "normal" array?

Answer (score 4):

In java type declarations precede variable names. E.g. `String b` means that `b` is an instance of `String` class. Java is statically an and strongly typed language.

So `Comparable[] a` says that `a` is an array of instances of some class implementing `Comparable` interface. Meaning each of the array's elements is either null or something, having `compareTo` method. See `less` method implementation and probably you'll find `compareTo` calls there.

A few examples of standard classes implementing comparable:

- Integer, so `new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` can be passed as a first argument to this function
- Double, so `new Double[] {1.5, 1.6, 1.8}` can be passed as a first argument
- String, so `new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}` can be passed as a first argument

Overall that construction allows to have the same piece of code handle different types adhering to a similar interface (meaning you don't have to write the same code for every new class you have). You can create some class implementing `Comparable` and reuse this code for this.

Also see [Comparable JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).